# JQuery Draggable Droppable and Sortable at the same time for DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to setup somme kind of drag and drop wysiwyg editor using JQuery UI.

I have succesfully setup the elements but they have a strange behavior.

It is almost impossible to sort items because of the constant flickering.

i setup my draggables like this:

```
el.draggable({
    containement:'.main-form-container',
    revert: "invalid",
    connectToSortable: '.sortable'
}).disableSelection();
```

If i dont set it as draggable the sortable will place the placeholder on itself! why?

Sometimes when an element is dropped into another it becomes ONE draggable element and seem tobe glued together. though that seems fixed with overriding sortable update:

```
update: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).css({
            position: 'relative',
            top:0,
            left:0,
            width: 'auto'
        });

        // init droppable draggable and sortable on this item
        setupDandD($(ui.item));
    }
```

and the setupDandD method:

```
setupDandD($('.form-container'));

    function setupDandD(el) {
        el.draggable({
            containement:'.main-form-container',
            revert: "invalid",
            connectToSortable: '.sortable'
        }).disableSelection();

        el.droppable({
            accept: '[data-section="toolbox"]',
            greedy: true,
            hoverClass: 'droppable-hovered',
            drop: handleDrop
        }).disableSelection();

        el.filter('.sortable').sortable({
            tolerance:'pointer',
            containement:'.main-form-container',
            connectWith: ".sortable:not(#" + $(this).id + ")",
            revert: 'invalid',
            helper: function () {
                return $(this);
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('here');
                $(ui.item).css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    top:0,
                    left:0,
                    width: 'auto'
                });
                setupDandD($(ui.item));
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    };
```

I guess I need to pickup some event somewhere on the sortable but i am quite lost now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well well! I found it!

Actually my biggest mistake was to mix droppable and sortable at the same time. I just had to use sortables and draggables with the connectToSortable option set.

The other weird behavior I had was the sortable trying to insert into itself. This is because sortable "connectWith" was set to a selector that returned self and therefor it instantly placed the placeholder on self when dragged. Quite logical actually!

To overcome this I just surrounded each child sortable with a div. It makes the div a sortable item and prevents triggering the events on self.

One thing to take into consideration when using draggable+sortable is that the sortable will always clone the object as it was when drag started. Meaning that even if you use a custom helper on the draggable, it will still insert the original item. For this I had to replace the item in the "stop" event of the sortable by the one i wanted if it came from my toolbox:

```
$('.main-form-container').sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    opacity: .35,
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    stop: function (e, t) {

        if (t.item.attr('data-section') == "toolbox") {
            $(t.item).replaceWith(createContainer());
        }

        $(".sortable").sortable({
            opacity: .35,
            placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
            connectWith: ".sortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

and here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorvan/ag659/

I realize there is probably a cleaner way of doing this last fix by overriding some maybe undocumented event in sortable/draggable, but that did the trick for me!